# How can i get the user's input after he's done typing instead of every character typed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I want to get the user's input from an input tag which also has an autocomplete option that would help the user choose from a list of countries but my problem is that when i try to use `console.log()` it shows every character typed by the user but I want to show me the result once he finished typing and choosing from the autocomplete dialog that would show up. How can i do that?

My code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="createFlight">
    <div>
        <input name="c" list="anrede" id="country">
        <datalist id="anrede"></datalist>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
var countries = ["French Polynesia", "Algeria", "Denmark", "South Africa", "United Arab Emirates", "Russia", "China", "Brazil", "Yemen", "Russian Federation", "Spain", "Iran", "United States", "Ivory Coast", "Ethiopia", "Australia", "Egypt", "Saudi Arabia", "Nigeria", "United Kingdom", "Mexico", "Ghana", "Switzerland", "Turkey", "Jordan", "Colombia", "Chad", "Argentina", "Norway", "Iceland", "Uzbekistan", "Solomon Islands", "Morocco", "France", "Sweden", "Papua New Guinea", "Greenland", "India", "Paraguay", "Venezuela", "Italy", "Honduras", "Cook Islands", "Comoros", "Libya", "Japan", "New Zealand", "Canada", "Kazakhstan", "Myanmar", "Syria", "Indonesia", "Netherlands", "Madagascar", "Chile", "Belgium", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Germany", "Greece", "Malaysia", "Mozambique", "Samoa", "Peru", "Tanzania", "Romania", "Turkmenistan", "Bahamas", "St. Helena", "Eritrea", "Kenya", "Sudan", "Mauritania", "Aruba", "Vanuatu", "Anguilla", "Dominican Republic", "Philippines", "Bahrain", "Botswana", "Somalia", "Cuba", "Costa Rica", "Bermuda", "Nepal", "Serbia", "Lebanon", "Thailand", "Central African Republic", "Barbados", "Iraq", "Pakistan", "Marshall Islands", "Gambia", "Burundi", "Mali", "Congo", "Malawi", "Vietnam", "New Caledonia", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Panama", "Bulgaria", "Netherlands Antilles", "Burkina Faso", "Czech Republic", "Equatorial Guinea", "Slovakia", "Hungary", "Zimbabwe", "Georgia", "Cape Verde", "Croatia", "Brunei", "Mongolia", "Belize", "Poland", "Bangladesh", "Angola", "Haiti", "French Guiana", "Bolivia", "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "Ireland", "Zambia", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "South Korea", "Guinea", "Sri Lanka", "Benin", "Senegal", "Ecuador", "Portugal", "Ukraine", "Kiribati", "Cayman Islands", "Taiwan", "Dominica", "Tunisia", "Cameroon", "Qatar", "Tajikistan", "Mayotte", "Uganda", "Cyprus", "British Virgin Islands", "null", "Finland", "Namibia", "Israel", "Tonga", "Armenia", "Faroe Islands", "Martinique", "Democratic Republic of Congo", "Sierra Leone", "North Korea", "Guatemala", "Kyrgyzstan", "Saint Pierre and Miquelon", "Tuvalu", "Wallis and Futuna Islands", "Maldives", "Gabon", "Guadeloupe", "Turks And Caicos Islands", "Guyana", "Gibraltar", "Grenada", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Afghanistan", "Hong Kong", "Lao People's Democratic Republic", "Fiji", "Nauru", "Niue", "Djibouti", "Estonia", "Rwanda", "Oman", "Jamaica", "Moldova", "Federated States of Micronesia", "Lithuania", "Kuwait", "Togo", "Slovenia", "Laos", "Latvia", "Luxembourg", "Monaco", "Macau", "Nicaragua", "Belarus", "Malta", "Liberia", "Falkland Islands", "Mauritius", "Lesotho", "Swaziland", "Uruguay", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Niger", "Norfolk Island", "Cote D'Ivoire", "Macedonia", "Guinea-Bissau", "Cambodia", "Bhutan", "Suriname", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Seychelles", "Palau", "Reunion", "El Salvador", "Singapore", "St. Lucia", "Montenegro", "Albania", "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya", "Northern Mariana Islands", "Sao Tome and Principe", "Antarctica", "Western Sahara", "Christmas Island", "Macao"];
var options = '';

for(var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++)
  options += '<option value="'+countries[i]+'" />';
document.getElementById('anrede').innerHTML = options;
var newVal;
$('#country').on("input propertychange", function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you mean the browser's autocomplete or your own autocomplete system? Also, does it matter if you get notified only when the user unfocus on the input?

Comment: So use `onchange`?

Answer (score 0):

I think `onchange` event is better:

```js
var countries = ["French Polynesia", "Algeria", "Denmark", "South Africa", "United Arab Emirates", "Russia", "China", "Brazil", "Yemen", "Russian Federation", "Spain", "Iran", "United States", "Ivory Coast", "Ethiopia", "Australia", "Egypt", "Saudi Arabia", "Nigeria", "United Kingdom", "Mexico", "Ghana", "Switzerland", "Turkey", "Jordan", "Colombia", "Chad", "Argentina", "Norway", "Iceland", "Uzbekistan", "Solomon Islands", "Morocco", "France", "Sweden", "Papua New Guinea", "Greenland", "India", "Paraguay", "Venezuela", "Italy", "Honduras", "Cook Islands", "Comoros", "Libya", "Japan", "New Zealand", "Canada", "Kazakhstan", "Myanmar", "Syria", "Indonesia", "Netherlands", "Madagascar", "Chile", "Belgium", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Germany", "Greece", "Malaysia", "Mozambique", "Samoa", "Peru", "Tanzania", "Romania", "Turkmenistan", "Bahamas", "St. Helena", "Eritrea", "Kenya", "Sudan", "Mauritania", "Aruba", "Vanuatu", "Anguilla", "Dominican Republic", "Philippines", "Bahrain", "Botswana", "Somalia", "Cuba", "Costa Rica", "Bermuda", "Nepal", "Serbia", "Lebanon", "Thailand", "Central African Republic", "Barbados", "Iraq", "Pakistan", "Marshall Islands", "Gambia", "Burundi", "Mali", "Congo", "Malawi", "Vietnam", "New Caledonia", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Panama", "Bulgaria", "Netherlands Antilles", "Burkina Faso", "Czech Republic", "Equatorial Guinea", "Slovakia", "Hungary", "Zimbabwe", "Georgia", "Cape Verde", "Croatia", "Brunei", "Mongolia", "Belize", "Poland", "Bangladesh", "Angola", "Haiti", "French Guiana", "Bolivia", "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "Ireland", "Zambia", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "South Korea", "Guinea", "Sri Lanka", "Benin", "Senegal", "Ecuador", "Portugal", "Ukraine", "Kiribati", "Cayman Islands", "Taiwan", "Dominica", "Tunisia", "Cameroon", "Qatar", "Tajikistan", "Mayotte", "Uganda", "Cyprus", "British Virgin Islands", "null", "Finland", "Namibia", "Israel", "Tonga", "Armenia", "Faroe Islands", "Martinique", "Democratic Republic of Congo", "Sierra Leone", "North Korea", "Guatemala", "Kyrgyzstan", "Saint Pierre and Miquelon", "Tuvalu", "Wallis and Futuna Islands", "Maldives", "Gabon", "Guadeloupe", "Turks And Caicos Islands", "Guyana", "Gibraltar", "Grenada", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Afghanistan", "Hong Kong", "Lao People's Democratic Republic", "Fiji", "Nauru", "Niue", "Djibouti", "Estonia", "Rwanda", "Oman", "Jamaica", "Moldova", "Federated States of Micronesia", "Lithuania", "Kuwait", "Togo", "Slovenia", "Laos", "Latvia", "Luxembourg", "Monaco", "Macau", "Nicaragua", "Belarus", "Malta", "Liberia", "Falkland Islands", "Mauritius", "Lesotho", "Swaziland", "Uruguay", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Niger", "Norfolk Island", "Cote D'Ivoire", "Macedonia", "Guinea-Bissau", "Cambodia", "Bhutan", "Suriname", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Seychelles", "Palau", "Reunion", "El Salvador", "Singapore", "St. Lucia", "Montenegro", "Albania", "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya", "Northern Mariana Islands", "Sao Tome and Principe", "Antarctica", "Western Sahara", "Christmas Island", "Macao"];
var options = '';

for(var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++){
  options += '<option value="'+countries[i]+'" />';
 }
document.getElementById('anrede').innerHTML = options;
var newVal;
$("#country").on("change", function(){
  console.log($(this).val());  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="c" list="anrede" id="country">
<datalist id="anrede"></datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works on the logic that a user has stopped typing if there's a keyup event that is not followed by a keydown event. Hence, for every keyup event, there is a 5 second wait. If there's no sequential keydown event, then we assume the user has stopped typing.

The code is as shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="createFlight">
    <div>
        <input name="c" list="anrede" id="country">
        <datalist id="anrede"></datalist>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
var countries = ["French Polynesia", "Algeria", "Denmark", "South Africa", "United Arab Emirates", "Russia", "China", "Brazil", "Yemen", "Russian Federation", "Spain", "Iran", "United States", "Ivory Coast", "Ethiopia", "Australia", "Egypt", "Saudi Arabia", "Nigeria", "United Kingdom", "Mexico", "Ghana", "Switzerland", "Turkey", "Jordan", "Colombia", "Chad", "Argentina", "Norway", "Iceland", "Uzbekistan", "Solomon Islands", "Morocco", "France", "Sweden", "Papua New Guinea", "Greenland", "India", "Paraguay", "Venezuela", "Italy", "Honduras", "Cook Islands", "Comoros", "Libya", "Japan", "New Zealand", "Canada", "Kazakhstan", "Myanmar", "Syria", "Indonesia", "Netherlands", "Madagascar", "Chile", "Belgium", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Germany", "Greece", "Malaysia", "Mozambique", "Samoa", "Peru", "Tanzania", "Romania", "Turkmenistan", "Bahamas", "St. Helena", "Eritrea", "Kenya", "Sudan", "Mauritania", "Aruba", "Vanuatu", "Anguilla", "Dominican Republic", "Philippines", "Bahrain", "Botswana", "Somalia", "Cuba", "Costa Rica", "Bermuda", "Nepal", "Serbia", "Lebanon", "Thailand", "Central African Republic", "Barbados", "Iraq", "Pakistan", "Marshall Islands", "Gambia", "Burundi", "Mali", "Congo", "Malawi", "Vietnam", "New Caledonia", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Panama", "Bulgaria", "Netherlands Antilles", "Burkina Faso", "Czech Republic", "Equatorial Guinea", "Slovakia", "Hungary", "Zimbabwe", "Georgia", "Cape Verde", "Croatia", "Brunei", "Mongolia", "Belize", "Poland", "Bangladesh", "Angola", "Haiti", "French Guiana", "Bolivia", "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "Ireland", "Zambia", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "South Korea", "Guinea", "Sri Lanka", "Benin", "Senegal", "Ecuador", "Portugal", "Ukraine", "Kiribati", "Cayman Islands", "Taiwan", "Dominica", "Tunisia", "Cameroon", "Qatar", "Tajikistan", "Mayotte", "Uganda", "Cyprus", "British Virgin Islands", "null", "Finland", "Namibia", "Israel", "Tonga", "Armenia", "Faroe Islands", "Martinique", "Democratic Republic of Congo", "Sierra Leone", "North Korea", "Guatemala", "Kyrgyzstan", "Saint Pierre and Miquelon", "Tuvalu", "Wallis and Futuna Islands", "Maldives", "Gabon", "Guadeloupe", "Turks And Caicos Islands", "Guyana", "Gibraltar", "Grenada", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Afghanistan", "Hong Kong", "Lao People's Democratic Republic", "Fiji", "Nauru", "Niue", "Djibouti", "Estonia", "Rwanda", "Oman", "Jamaica", "Moldova", "Federated States of Micronesia", "Lithuania", "Kuwait", "Togo", "Slovenia", "Laos", "Latvia", "Luxembourg", "Monaco", "Macau", "Nicaragua", "Belarus", "Malta", "Liberia", "Falkland Islands", "Mauritius", "Lesotho", "Swaziland", "Uruguay", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Niger", "Norfolk Island", "Cote D'Ivoire", "Macedonia", "Guinea-Bissau", "Cambodia", "Bhutan", "Suriname", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Seychelles", "Palau", "Reunion", "El Salvador", "Singapore", "St. Lucia", "Montenegro", "Albania", "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya", "Northern Mariana Islands", "Sao Tome and Principe", "Antarctica", "Western Sahara", "Christmas Island", "Macao"];
var options = '';

for(var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++)
  options += '<option value="'+countries[i]+'" />';
document.getElementById('anrede').innerHTML = options;
var newVal; 

var checkIfTypingIsFinished;//timer that checks if typing is finished   
$('#country').keyup(function(){//if typing is paused   
    checkIfTypingIsFinished = setTimeout(doneTyping, 5000/*5 seconds*/); 
}); 
$('#country').keydown(function(){//if typing is resumed
    clearTimeout(checkIfTypingIsFinished); 
});  
function doneTyping ()//if user has finished typing, display the text
{ 
    console.log($('#country').val());
    clearTimeout(checkIfTypingIsFinished); 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps.